# Atom packages list without disabled ones

Tags: atom-editor

How can I get a list of all installed and activated plugins in Atom?

I can use `apm list --installed --bare` to get all installed packages but I don't want to include disabled ones. And I have a lot of disabled packages.

Comment: I think this is a bug: [https://github.com/atom/apm/pull/617](https://github.com/atom/apm/pull/617)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `apm` can't list only enabled packages. You can perhaps use [`package-manager-commands`](https://atom.io/packages/package-manager-commands) and list all enabled packages to disable:

```
package-manager:disable-package
```

Comment: Yes, surely you can.

Answer (score 3):

go to atom -> install new package -> and you will see all the installed and activated packages first

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::getActivePackages()` which will return list of active packages.

See official documentation here:

- [getActivePackages()](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.12.5/PackageManager#instance-getActivePackages)

Hope this will help you some way (y).

Answer (score 1):

`apm list --installed --enabled`

as of [`apm == 1.18.12`](https://github.com/atom/apm/releases/tag/v1.18.12).